# Cartesian product when dimension is None

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cartesian-product

This is related to an implementation issue in TensorFlow. I have a tensor `H` of size `(batch_size, time_steps, 256)` (but `batch_size` and `time_steps` are `None` during build time).

I want to compute a tensor `A` of the shape `(batch_size, time_steps, time_steps, n_dim)` which is a Cartesian product across the time dimension. Thus, in simple terms:

```
A[:,i,j,:] = some_func(H[:,i,:], H[:,j,:])
```

Since the number of time_steps is `None` at time of building graph, what would be an elegant way to compute `A`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TensorFlow's broadcasting properties to construct cartesian products between tensors by expanding one tensor with an additional dimension and multiplying it with the other tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None, 256), dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None, 256), dtype=tf.float32)

A_ = tf.expand_dims(A, axis=1)

A_*B
```

Gives

```
<tf.Tensor 'mul_1:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 256) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: This does not serve the exact purpose. The above `A_*B` would be of the shape `(batch_size, 1, num_steps, 256)` and will still be the element-wise multiplication of A and B. This is not Cartesian product of the two tensors

Comment: You are right, I was too quick to answer. I'll see if I can update my answer. It should be possible through broadcasting though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the case when the size of `time_steps` axis is specified (i.e. is not `None`). We can easily use `K.repeat_elements` and `K.tile` to form the tensors for cartesian product:

```py
from keras import layers, models
from keras import backend as K

def some_func(a, b):
    # define the some_func here
    return a + b

def cart_prod(x):
    shp = K.int_shape(x)[1]
    x_rep = K.repeat_elements(x, shp, axis=1)
    x_tile = K.tile(x, [1, shp, 1])
    res = some_func(x_rep, x_tile)
    return K.reshape(res, [-1, shp, shp, K.shape(res)[-1]])

inp = layers.Input((3, 2))
out = layers.Lambda(cart_prod)(inp)
model = models.Model(inp, out)

model.predict(np.arange(6).reshape(1, 3, 2))
```

Output:

```py
array([[[[ 0.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  6.]],

        [[ 2.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  6.],
         [ 6.,  8.]],

        [[ 4.,  6.],
         [ 6.,  8.],
         [ 8., 10.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Yes, it's easier to do this in your way as well when the `time_steps` are known. One way is to pad the time_steps dimension and fixate it and follow the same procedure. But that's not what I want to do.
I was looking for some elegant manner to still be able to work with `time_steps` being unknown.